# Failing to perform click on navigation bar custom button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController with a navigation bar in which i have 3 custom buttons that i have programatically assigned click events. The navigation bar looks like this:

[image]

The issue i'm facing somehow is that the first 2 buttons ('Home' & 'Events') can click well and respond accordingly, but the third ('Today') won't click. I am puzzled as to why and thought maybe this is the spot where normally the Navigation Bar title is so maybe there is some conflict but i can't seem to resolve it

The method adding these buttons and click events is as follows:

```
func addCustomBtnsNavBar(){
    self.title = nil
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

    let viewLeftItem = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 5, width: 120, height: 40))

    let button1a = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 5, width: 50, height: 40))
    button1a.setTitle("Home", for: .normal)
    button1a.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Nolasco Sans", size: 16)
    button1a.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)

    button1a.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openAboutUs), for: .touchUpInside)

    let button1b = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(x: 60, y: 5, width: 50, height: 40))
    button1b.setTitle("Events", for: .normal)
    button1b.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Nolasco Sans", size: 16)
    button1b.setTitleColor(Util.hexStringToUIColor(hex: Constants.lightGrey), for: .normal)
    button1b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openEventsPage), for: .touchUpInside)

    let button1c = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(x: 120, y: 5, width: 50, height: 40))
    button1c.setTitle("Today", for: .normal)
    button1c.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Nolasco Sans", size: 16)
    button1c.setTitleColor(Util.hexStringToUIColor(hex: Constants.lightGrey), for: .normal)
    button1c.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openEventsPage), for: .touchUpInside)
    let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: viewLeftItem)

    let viewRightItem = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30))

    let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(x: 35, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    button2.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "blue_circle"), for: .normal)
    button2.setTitle(getInitials(), for: .normal)
    button2.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Google Sans", size: 12)
    button2.setTitleColor(.white, for: .focused)
    button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didTapRightButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    viewLeftItem.addSubview(button1a)
    viewLeftItem.addSubview(button1b)
    viewLeftItem.addSubview(button1c)

    viewRightItem.addSubview(button2)

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: viewRightItem)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewLeftItem`'s width is 120, and the `x` origin of your third button is `120`.

I do believe that if you'll set `viewLeftItem`'s `clipToBounds` property to `true`, you won't be able to see it at all.

You have to increase the width of your container to `170` according to the origin and the width of your third button.

Comment: I was afraid it would be something this trivial but you're absolutely right. It's a calculations issue.